# The best way to set all the datagrid cells of a row with the same value

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, filter, datagrid

I would like to improve this code whose goal is to work like the excel filters. If all of the checkboxes of the selected row are true, then the function (trigered by a button) set them all false, if they are all false, then they are set to true, and if at least one of them is `false` or `true`, then they all become true. But my code is only working when they are all `true` or `false`. The other condition is not always working, this is because of the last part of the code which is not throwing the right result.
The checkboxes are in the column 3 and from 7 until 19 of a total of 21.

```
public void seleciona_check()
{
  for (int i = 7; i < grid_lic.ColumnCount-1 ; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 7; j < grid_lic.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
    {
      if (grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[j].Value.ToString() == grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString())
      {
       if (grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString() == "True")
        {
          Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = false);
          Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = false);
        }
        else if (grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString() == "False")
        {
          Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = true);
          Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = true);
        }
      }
      else if (grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[j].Value.ToString() != grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString())
      {
        Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = true);
        Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[j].Value = true);
        Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value = true);
        Convert.ToBoolean(grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share some more information about this issue. e.g. a screen shot of grid may be helpful to understand real problem.

Comment: I've already inserted an image of the datagrid. When I select a row with all checkboxes true (or filled) and apply the filter, they don't become false.

Comment: The column nr.3 corresponde to the column 'bloqueado'. I changed its index so that it is shown in the position 6 of the datagrid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on rows then you should iterate through the rows and then in each column of a row.If you want to work on a specific row then you have to access the current row index and use it to access the cell.

You can start with the value from the first column and check if it changes while iterating. If it changes then call a function to set the values as desired, if not call the function at the end.

```
public void seleciona_check()
    {
        bool changed = false; //boolean to see if something changed 
        bool compareTo=(bool)grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value; // take the first value as reference point
        for (int j = 7; j < grid_lic.ColumnCount - 1; j++) // for loop to check
        {
            if ((bool)grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[j].Value != compareTo)
            {
                changed = true; 
                SetAllValues(changed);
                break; //no need to go on if there are true and false values
            }
        }
        if (changed == false) SetAllValues ( compareTo );
    }

    public void SetAllValues(bool toSet)
    {
        for (int j = 7; j < grid_lic.ColumnCount - 1; j++) // for loop to check
        {
            grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[j].Value = toSet;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to compare the columns cells value to the value of column 3, of the row selected , I just want to set all true if they are all false or at least one false or true, and to set them all false if all of them are true., like in excel filters. The column 3 is out of the cycle because between it and the column 7 there are cells that don't have checkboxes and are not be changed to true or false. It is now in the position 6 in termos of visualization because I changed the index visualization in datagrid but its actual index is 3.